# How to give priority to conda package over pip one?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, package, conda

With my virtual environment activated, I see with `conda list` that my pandas version is 0.24.0. When I do the same with `pip list`, I see the version is 0.22.0 (probably an older version that I installed before using conda). When I import pandas in python (3.6), the pandas version is 0.22.0.

Why and how to force the loading of the conda package?

EDIT: MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Comment: `pip` *might* not be tied to the python in your virtual environment. It's usually better practice to use `python -m pip list`, since that explicitly ties `pip` to the python environment you are using. Furthermore, if you don't have a `conda` env activated, `conda list` could be listing packages in the base install of `conda`

Comment: Have you activated the environment? If you use `import sys; print(sys.path)` what do you get? `where pip` in your terminal might also give you some clues

Comment: python -m pip list gives the same: pandas 0.22.0. conda list is run when my virtual environment is activated and gives 0.24.0

Comment: Ok, so is `python -m pip list` run when the environment is also activated?

Comment: Yes. Also (still with my virtual env activated), command `which pip` gives :  `/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/pip, /Users/me/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pip and /Users/me/miniconda3/bin/pip`

Comment: `where pip | head -n 1` tells you which one it will default to. It looks like the first one you get doesn't source from `.../myenv/`, but from the base miniconda. Can you check output of `echo $CONDA_PREFIX`? Also, `where python | head -n 1` will tell you which interpreter it's using

Comment: The `echo` command gives `/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/myenv`. The command `where` does not exist on MacOS. The equivalent seems to be `which`.

Comment: Ah, I'm using `zsh` which may include `where`. Either way, not a massive deal

Comment: So it  seems that the package does not come from my environment but from another place, so my initial question: how to give priority of one package over another?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194393/discussion-between-c-nivs-and-patrick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR is in Possible Fix at the bottom

A few notes, and these may or may not answer the question, but I think this is a bit better than dumping everything into comments. These assume that your environment is activated, for these examples, my environment is called `new36`. I am also on MacOS with High Sierra 10.13.6.

### Checking `conda` vs `pip` locations

First, let's check to make sure `conda` and `pip` are both looking in the same environment. To find information surrounding `conda`, check:

```sh
conda info
```

I get the following:

```sh
active environment : new36
    active env location : /Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/mm92400/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/mm92400/.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.8
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 3.6.3.final.0
# extra info excluded
```

The `active env location` is what we're concerned with. This should be a directory that contains the directory of `pip`:

```sh
which pip | head -n 1

/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/bin/pip
```

If `pip` does not sit in a directory under where `conda` lives, this could be part of the issue.

### Verifying the import path of python

You should be able to check where python is sourcing files from via `sys.path`:

```py
import sys

sys.path
['', '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python36.zip', '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6', '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

This is a `list`, and that's important to note. Note how my `sys.path` does not have any directories that source from a file/folder based on a base install of `conda`, nor any of the Framework installs of python on my Mac. `import` will search these directories ('' is cwd) *in order*, pulling down the first instance of a package that it finds. If your `sys.path` has an element earlier than your conda env that contains `pandas`, this is your problem.

#### Verbose python

You can also verify where the pandas package is being sourced from using the verbose mode of python, `python -v`:

```py
# you have gotten here by running python -v in the terminal
# there's a whole bunch of comments that pop out that I'm going to omit here

# Now run
import pandas

~snip~
# code object from '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__pycache__/_version.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pandas._version' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x107952b00>
import 'pandas' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104572b38>
```

Note how the `code object` path matches where I expect python to source that package from

## Possible Fix

You can hack on `sys.path`, though I'm not sure how recommended that is. You can prioritize where directories are in `sys.path` without modifying `sys.path` in your script like:

```sh
env PYTHONPATH=$(find $CONDA_PREFIX -type d -name "site-packages" | head -n 1) python
```

which will take you into an interpreter and `sys.path` will look like:

```py
import sys
sys.path
['', '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages', ...]
```

Where now the first directory it will check is the `conda env` site-packages. Because `sys.path` is a `list`, it will be traversed in order. The way to prioritize which one you want to use is by injecting that particular directory into the `sys.path` first. If I were to write a script like:

```py
import sys

print(f"I prioritized {sys.path[1]}")
```

And ran it using `env PYTHONPATH=$(find $CONDA_PREFIX -type d -name "site-packages" | head -n 1) python somefile.py` I would get:

```sh
env PYTHONPATH=$(find $CONDA_PREFIX -type d -name "site-packages" | head -n 1) python somefile.py
I prioritized /Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Alternatively, you can `insert` into `sys.path`, but I can say definitively that this is *not* recommended and quite fragile:

```py
import os, sys

try:
    conda_env = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']
except KeyError:
    raise KeyError("The env var $CONDA_PREFIX was not found. Please check that your conda environment was activated")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(conda_env):
    if 'site-packages' in dirs:
        syspath_add = os.path.join(root, 'site-packages')
        break
else:
    raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find site-packages!")

sys.path.insert(0, syspath_add)

sys.path
# ['/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '', ...]
```

Comment: So nice from your part to take time to help me! Strangely enough, my sys.path command gives a list of directories and *none* of them contains myenv!

Comment: @Patrick Now *that's* interesting. Are you sure `myenv` is activated? Also, with `myenv` activated, if you run `python -c 'import os; print(os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'])'` what happens?

Comment: myenv is activated (my prompt shows it in parentheses). Result of the command is `Users/me/miniconda3/envs/myenv`

Comment: I think I found the problem (because of you!). The command `which python` gives `/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/python` and after `/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python`. If I execute `/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python` now pd.__version__ is 0.24.0. I don't know why the python of my activated environment is ranked 2nd in the list.

Comment: Could be how the `$PATH` environment variable is constructed. Entering any command in the terminal will search the path for a matching binary, and when `activate myenv` is called, it could be appending `$CONDA_PREFIX/bin` to `$PATH`, rather than *pre*pending, which would cause the older path to be found first. Check the output of `$PATH` before and after `activate myenv` is called

Comment: I tried it in a new terminal console. It's funny: before I activate my env,`which python` shows `.../miniconda3/bin/python` and after it shows `.../miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python` *then* `.../miniconda3/bin/python`. So it works in new console! I don't know why `myenv/bin/python` was relegated 2nd in original console but I know now that exiting and entering again will do the job. Many thanks to you!