# Conveniently priorize local python package vs. environment

Tags: python, git, import, repository, virtual-environment

Similar question: [How to give priority to conda package over pip one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430430/how-to-give-priority-to-conda-package-over-pip-one)

I am working in a team where we have setup a virtual python environment for everyone to conveniently have access to our packages.
One of the packages is a repo which is work in progress, i.e. the current master is stored in the environment, but it is updated frequently.

Now I would like to use my personal, local clone where I am working on a development branch. When I am done, the code will be merged in the master and thus made available for everyone.

However, if I simply write `import my_module`, python will use the master from the environment, instead of my local clone stored in /users/me/my_module

I realise that I could switch the order of loading by using

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/users/me/my_module")
import my_module

print(my_module.__file__)
# '/users/me/my_module.__init.__.py'
```

This solution is proposed, but not recommended, in the similar question above. I especially dislike it, because I will have to remove those lines before submitting to master.

Another solution is to drop out from the environment while working on the dev branch, but then I lose all access to the other packages from the env.

Another solution from the similiar question is to modify the environment by adding
`env PYTHONPATH=$(find $CONDA_PREFIX -type d -name "site-packages" | head -n 1) python`
I assume in my case it would be something like `env PYTHONPATH=$("/users/me/my_module" | head -n 1) python` -> Here, I would not be able to use the master from the env anymore, without logging out and changing my env again.

Generally, I can only think of two options:

1. Somehow easily switch the used repo from env to local and back
2. Always use the env repo, but switch to the remote dev branch on-the-fly and back.